# Trouble inserting data into a SQL Server CE databse

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I am new to C# and was experimenting a bit trying to insert stuff into a SQL Server CE database. I don't understand why this code is not working. I am getting a

> *System.Data.SqlServerCE.SqlCeException*

error pointing to the `com1.ExecuteNonQuery();` line when the program is run.

I am attaching my code that i am using to insert into the  table.

```
//Connecting to SQL Server
SqlCeConnection conn1 = new SqlCeConnection();
conn1.ConnectionString = connection; //connection is a string variable which has the connection details
conn1.Open();

SqlCeCommand com1 = new SqlCeCommand();
com1.Connection = conn1;
com1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
com1.CommandText = "INSERT into data(pname, budget, dcommision, advance, phone, cdetails, mail) values(@pname , @budget, @dcommision, @advance, @phone, @cdetails, @mail)";

com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", textBox8.Text.Trim());
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@budget", budget);
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dcommision", textBox7.Text.Trim());
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@advance", advance);
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cdetails", richTextBox1.Text.Trim());
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", textBox3.Text.Trim());

com1.ExecuteNonQuery();     //Executing the SQL query

com1.Dispose();     //Closing SQL Server connection
conn1.Close();
```

Is something wrong with my query? I am really a newbie so some help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you find more detail about this exception? E.g. does it have an `.InnerException` that would explain in more detail what's wrong?? Also: are you using SQL Server CE 3.5 or 4.0 ?

Comment: Provide full information about exception including stack trace and inner exceptions if available, please.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll   {"The column cannot contain null values. [ Column name = cname,Table name = data ]"}

Comment: that is silly of me i didnt know i could check details that way, now i know what caused the error thanks sorry abt the false alarm i am really new to this so ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table `data` have also column `cname` which you don't include in `INSERT` list, and column i marked as `NOT NULL`. Include the column too into `INSERT` list or provide `DEFAULT` value for this column in DB.